# What is the covariant derivative of the Ricci Tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, differentiation

How do I take the covariant derivative of the Ricci Tensor? Could someone be so kind as to give me the process of how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

The covariant derivative is defined as:
$$
\nabla_\mu V^\nu= \partial_\mu V^\nu + \Gamma^\nu_{\mu\gamma}V^\gamma\tag{1}
$$
And Christoffel symbols of the second kind are taken as
$$
\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\gamma} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\delta\nu}\left(g_{\mu\delta,\gamma}+g_{\gamma\delta,\mu}-g_{\mu\gamma,\delta} \right)\tag{2}
$$
This should be enough to find the covariant derivative in general, not just for the Ricci tensor specifically.